# Install CPAN without bringing in gcc, g++, etc

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, cpan

From what I've searched, it looks like there's only one way to install CPAN in Ubuntu, installing build-essential. Which brings in other dependencies like gcc and g++, which I don't want to install. Is CPAN actually in build-essential? If not is there a way to install CPAN so that we don't have to bring in other dependencies build-essential brings.

Comment: CPAN : `/usr/bin/cpan` is provided by the package `perl`. .... Please do `$ ls /usr/bin/cpan` to know that the `cpan` command / the CPAN module is already present by default.

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks like cpan is present by default in ubuntu.